# Java Script - Count for even number of open and closed brackets

Tags: javascript, count

I want to make sure that a string contains an even number of closed and open brackets.

How can I count the number of open and closed brackets of a string in JavaScript and then compare the results?

Preferable without a use of regex.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you only want to count? Or also check malformed expressions like `())(`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some straightforward JavaScript:

```
function count_chars(s) {
  var i = s.length, r = {};
  while (i--) r[s[i]] = r[s[i]] ? r[s[i]]+1 : 1;
  return r;
}

var str = 'ab(sdf)sdf(sdf))';
var chars = count_chars(str);

console.log('( count = ' + (chars['('] || 0));
console.log(') count = ' + (chars[')'] || 0));
console.log('{ count = ' + (chars['{'] || 0));
```

returns:

```
( count = 2
) count = 3
{ count = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.split`:

```
str.split("(").length === str.split(")").length
```